# Renaming Hidden and System files Command

Tags: batch-file, delete-file, file-rename, xcopy

I'm trying to figure out a way to rename Desktop.ini to *.ini and back again. The problem is I need to do this with the attributes in tact (So I cannot remove hidden and system and then rename). The only solution I have come up with is xcopy and del but I am having trouble with the syntax on options, source options and destination options.

This is what I have come up with:

```
@ECHO OFF

xcopy /H /R Desktop.ini Desktop.txt /K
del /Q /AHS Desktop.ini
xcopy /H /R Desktop.txt Desktop.ini /K
del /Q /AHS Desktop.txt

Pause

exit /b
```

Comment: If you reveal the actual task then a solution may be more obvious.

Comment: Is there any solution to this yet? I had encountered this scenario too..

Answer (score 12):

When using `ren` you must remove `hidden` and `system` flags, rename the file, then set the flags again:

```
attrib -s -h desktop.ini
ren desktop.ini desktop.txt
attrib +s +h desktop.txt
```

If you can't do that, you have to use something else, e.g. VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0)).Name = WScript.Arguments(1)
```

or PowerShell:

```
Rename-Item 'desktop.ini' 'desktop.txt' -Force
```

Comment: As I stated originally I need the attributes in tact, I cannot get rid of the attributes and read them without having to rename the file again. "The problem is I need to do this with the attributes in tact (So I cannot remove hidden and system and then rename)."

Comment: Note to googlers: **`-s`** marks a *system* file, while **`-h`** means a normal hidden file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute#DOS_and_Windows

Answer (score -3):

For delete all Desktop.ini Files, you can use

```
DEL /S Desktop.ini
```

Comment: That would be fine if I merely wanted to delete the files. I need to rename Desktop.ini (With attributes hidden and system) to *.* and back again (With same attributes)